# Does $a_n + b_n \to c$ and $a_{n_j}, b_{n_j} \to a,b$ imply that $a_n, b_n \to a,b$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Everything here is on a Hilbert space. Suppose I have two sequence $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that
$$a_n + b_n \to c$$
and, for a subsequence $n_j$ of $n$,
$$a_{n_j} \to a$$
$$b_{n_j} \to b.$$

From this information, does it follow that $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to a$ for the full sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a_n=(-1)^n$, $b_{n}=(-1)^{n+1}$, $n_j=2j$ is a counterexample both to the current statement and the one that you most likely had in mind (with $b_n\to b$ instead of $b_n\to a$).

Comment: lol you're right thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take any sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ that has a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_j})_{j\geq 0}$ (for example a bounded sequence), and define $b_n=c-a_n$. Then $(a_n+b_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is constant, thus converges to $c$, and $(b_{n_j})_{j\geq 0}$ converges to $c-\lim_j a_{n_j}$, even if $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ does not converge.